# Razor view master page and ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a master page (master.cshtml), a child master page(dashboard_master.cshtml) and an actually page (dashboard.cshtml)

dashboard.cshtml is using a strongly typed model "com.models.dashboard"

The thing is, there is a html link inside the "dashbhoard_master" that needs to be changed based on a property inside the model class (com.models.dashboard)

I specified the @model com.models.dashboard in the dashboard.cshtml, so how can its master page know about the model property?

Not sure if that makes any sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Looks like I can just use the @Model.[property] directly in the master and it works this time. Don't know why it didn't' work for me the first time. Sorry guys